# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xN(x)dx = m$

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus

When $N(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ show that the mean of $N$ is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = m$$

I have approached this in two ways as I wasn't sure on which would lead me towards the right answer, but also because I got stuck on the next step.

First approach:

by taking $u = \frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ then its derivative $m-du\sigma^2=xdx$

$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^u(m-du\sigma^2)$$ Although this does not lead me to the right place.

Second approach:

$$N^2(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\implies\frac{1}{\sigma2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{\frac{-[(x-m)^2+(y-m)^2]}{2\sigma^2}}dxdy$$

Although I'm stuck as I'm unsure on how to proceed with the numerator in the exponential. I know it can be converted into polar coordinates somehow, but what to do with the $-m$ in the brackets?

Any hints on the right approach to take?

Comment: One way is when $m=0$ it's an odd function, so the integral must be $0$ over that symmetrical domain. You can then get it for arbitrary $m$ by doing a change of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_{\sigma}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$.

Substitute $x-m$ to $y$. Then $x=y+m$, and use $\int_{-\infty}^\infty N_{\sigma}(x)dx=1$ and $yN_0(y)$ is odd function.

Then the integral changes...
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xN_\sigma(x-m)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(y+m)N_0(y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yN_0(y)dy+m\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}N_0(y)dy$$
$yN_0(y)$ is odd. Therefore the value is $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $e^{-x^2}$ decays at $\infty$ and $-\infty$:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{xe^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\sigma y+m)\frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy=\\
=\sigma\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{ye^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dy+m=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}(-y)e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy+m=\\
=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{d}{dy}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy+m=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(0-0)+m=m$$